# Find out which AWS regions have resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

Is there a quick way to find out which regions have any resources in my account?  I'm specifically using the AWS .NET SDK but the answer likely applies to other AWS SDKs and the CLI since they all seem to be just wrappers to the REST API.  I can obviously run all the `List*` methods across all regions but I'm thinking there must be a more optimal way to decide whether to query the entire region or not.  Maybe something in billing, but it also needs to be relatively up-to-date, maybe within the last 5 minutes or so.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single way to list all resources in an AWS account or in multiple regions.

Some people say that **Resource Groups** are a good way to list resources, but I don't think they include "everything" in an account.

AWS Config does an excellent job of keeping track of resources and their history, but it is also limited in the types of resources it tracks.

My favourite way to list resources is to use [nccgroup/aws-inventory: Discover resources created in an AWS account](https://github.com/nccgroup/aws-inventory). It's a simple HTML/JavaScript file that makes all the 'List' calls for you and shows them in a nicely formatted list.

Comment: Thanks for confirming John.  I already have multiple calls to obtain resources which works as it should but I was just trying to optimize it.

Comment: Rereading your answer, you say "there is no single way to list all resources."  That's not exactly what I'm after.  I'm just trying to determine if there are *any* resources (a simple yes/no) before I start querying a region.  Maybe that gives other options?

Comment: Re-pinging you since I see you work at AWS. :)  Could you check out my comment above?  I just want to make sure your answer would still apply when I'm looking for a yes/no, not listing all resources.

Comment: Regions can be "disabled". For example, all regions since Hong Kong are disabled on accounts by default. So, you could check the account settings and totally skip-over disabled regions. The [describe-regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-regions.html) command can return a list of Enabled regions. See also: [Managing AWS Regions - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande-manage.html)

Comment: Ok, that's not perfect but it's better.  Thanks!